# How can I pass more a value from my HTML to inside of a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive:

```
app.directive('testDir', [function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            var abc=<some string passed from the html>;
        }
    };
}])
```

I want the directive to be something like this:

```
<div testDir='abcd'>xx</div>
```

How can I read the value 'abcd' when inside my directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either access it off of your `attr`

```
app.directive('testDir', [function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            var abc=attr.testDir;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Or by creating an isolated scope (with `test-dir="'test'")

```
app.directive('testDir', [function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope: {
           testDir : "="
        },
        link: function (scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            var abc=scope.testDir;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Note:
Your `<html/>` is wrong, you need `test-dir` not `testDir`

```
<div test-dir='abcd'>xx</div>
```

Comment: Thanks :-) I'll accept the answer. I have another question about multiple params. I will post another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Through the `attrs` variable (3rd argument in the linking process).

```
var abc =  attr.testDir
```

If you needed to pass a AngularJS context variable, then you need to use $parse.

```
var abc= $parse(attr.testDir)(scope)
```